# Alternatives to SQL union

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following SQL script, it currently displays the count of rows within a time range based on a given time. E.g. 15 mins before & 15 mins after the given time, 30 mins before & 30 mins after the time etc. It works fine but I need to change it from a union for a performance perspective. Any ideas on other approaches on how I can achieve this with a single select / table?

```
DECLARE @GameNumber int
DECLARE @EventType int

SET @GameNumber = 116
SET @EventType = 1

SELECT 'Between -120 mins and -90 mins' as TimePeriod
      ,COUNT(*) 
FROM attendance ta
LEFT OUTER JOIN SubStations sub
ON TA_ServiceNumber = sub.ServiceNumber
AND TA_DoorNumber = sub.DoorNumber
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] pro
ON ta.TA_GameNumber = pro.prd_GameNumber
INNER JOIN dbo.producttypes prot
ON ta.Eventtype = prot.PRD_TypeID AND @EventType = prot.PRD_EventTypeID

WHERE GameNumber = @GameNumber
AND EventType = @EventType
AND ta.TA_TimeAndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -120, pro.GameTime) AND DATEADD(minute, -90, pro.GameTime)

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Between -90 mins and -60 mins' as TimePeriod
      ,COUNT(*) AS Flow
FROM attendance ta
INNER JOIN TA_OperationCode toc
ON ta.TA_OperationCode = toc.OperationCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN SubStations sub
ON TA_ServiceNumber = sub.ServiceNumber
AND TA_DoorNumber = sub.DoorNumber
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] pro
ON ta.TA_GameNumber = pro.prd_GameNumber
INNER JOIN dbo.producttypes prot
ON ta.TA_Eventtype = prot.PRD_TypeID AND @EventType = prot.PRD_EventTypeID

WHERE GameNumber = @GameNumber
AND EventType = @EventType 
AND ta.TA_TimeAndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -90, pro.GameTime) AND DATEADD(minute, -60, pro.GameTime)

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Between -60 mins and -45 mins' as TimePeriod
      ,COUNT(*) AS Flow
FROM attendance ta
INNER JOIN TA_OperationCode toc
ON ta.TA_OperationCode = toc.OperationCode
LEFT JOIN SubStationssub
ON TA_ServiceNumber = sub.ServiceNumber
AND TA_DoorNumber = sub.DoorNumber
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] pro
ON ta.TA_GameNumber = pro.prd_GameNumber
INNER JOIN dbo.producttypes prot
ON ta.TA_Eventtype = prot.PRD_TypeID AND @EventType = prot.PRD_EventTypeID

WHERE GameNumber = @GameNumber
AND EventType = @EventType
AND ta.TA_TimeAndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -60, pro.GameTime) AND DATEADD(minute, -45, pro.GameTime)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT v.TimePeriod, COUNT(*) 
FROM attendance ta LEFT OUTER JOIN
     SubStations sub
     ON TA_ServiceNumber = sub.ServiceNumber AND
        TA_DoorNumber = sub.DoorNumber INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Products] pro
        ON ta.TA_GameNumber = pro.prd_GameNumber INNER JOIN 
        dbo.producttypes prot
        ON ta.Eventtype = prot.PRD_TypeID AND
        @EventType = prot.PRD_EventTypeID CROSS APPLY
        (VALUES (CASE WHEN ta.TA_TimeAndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -120, pro.GameTime) AND DATEADD(minute, -90, pro.GameTime)
                      THEN 'Between -90 mins and -60 mins'
                      WHEN ta.TA_TimeAndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -90, pro.GameTime) AND DATEADD(minute, -60, pro.GameTime)
                      THEN 'Between -90 mins and -60 mins'
                      . . .
                 END)
        ) v(TimePeriod)
WHERE GameNumber = @GameNumber AND EventType = @EventType
GROUP BY v.TimePeriod
ORDER BY MIN(ta.TA_TimeAndDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - looks great. But I get the following error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.

Comment: @SamFarr . . . The `VALUES` table value constructor is in all supported versions of SQL Server:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.  Perhaps there is some subtle syntax error.

Comment: I changed the (VALUES to (SELECT and it worked. Many thanks. Have marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

why not simply GROUP BY The Case Statement:
EG

```
select 
case 
when ta.TA_TimeAndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -120, pro.GameTime) AND DATEADD(minute, -90, pro.GameTime)
 then 'Between -120 mins and -90 mins' 
when ta.TA_TimeAndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -90, pro.GameTime) AND DATEADD(minute, -60, pro.GameTime)
 then 'Between -90 mins and -60 mins'
when ta.TA_TimeAndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -60, pro.GameTime) AND DATEADD(minute, -45, pro.GameTime)
 then 'Between -60 mins and -45 mins'
else ''
END 

 as TimePeriod,
 count(*) as Flow


 FROM attendance ta
INNER JOIN TA_OperationCode toc
ON ta.TA_OperationCode = toc.OperationCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN SubStations sub
ON TA_ServiceNumber = sub.ServiceNumber
AND TA_DoorNumber = sub.DoorNumber
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] pro
ON ta.TA_GameNumber = pro.prd_GameNumber
INNER JOIN dbo.producttypes prot
ON ta.TA_Eventtype = prot.PRD_TypeID AND @EventType = prot.PRD_EventTypeID

WHERE GameNumber = @GameNumber
AND EventType = @EventType 

AND ta.TA_TimeAndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -120, pro.GameTime) AND DATEADD(minute, -45, pro.GameTime)

group by
case 
when ta.TA_TimeAndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -120, pro.GameTime) AND DATEADD(minute, -90, pro.GameTime)
 then 'Between -120 mins and -90 mins' 
when ta.TA_TimeAndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -90, pro.GameTime) AND DATEADD(minute, -60, pro.GameTime)
 then 'Between -90 mins and -60 mins'
when ta.TA_TimeAndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -60, pro.GameTime) AND DATEADD(minute, -45, pro.GameTime)
 then 'Between -60 mins and -45 mins'
else ''
END
```

if the inner join diff is important you can add it as a left join instead and check for not null in the where `clause eg:

```
AND (toc.OperationCode is not null or ta.TA_TimeAndDate > DATEADD(minute, -90, pro.GameTime))
```

`